# Setting up Neo4J with Golang

Tags: go, neo4j

I am setting up Go with Neo4j on a live project for one of the microservices

I went through the docs around setting up the same but it does not show the best practice to do the same **(specifically globally and pass around the session instance throughout the application)**

This is what I am doing to setup the same, was wondering if this is the right approach:

```golang
// app.go

import ""github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/neo4j""

type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    DB *sqlx.DB
    Neo4j neo4j.Session // setting neo4j session globally for injection
}

// =============================
// Neo4j initialization 
// =============================
    driver, err2 := neo4j.NewDriver(
        neo4jConfig.connstring,
        neo4j.BasicAuth(neo4jConfig.username, neo4jConfig.password, ""),
        func(c *neo4j.Config){
            c.Encrypted = false
        },
    )
    checkForErrors(err2, "Cannot connect to NEO4J")
    defer driver.Close()
    session, err3 := driver.NewSession(neo4j.SessionConfig{})
    a.Neo4j = session //  assigning the session instance
```

Now this will be injected as a dependency in the `repo` package where the queries are being executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [example in the readme](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver#minimum-viable-snippet) says the following:

```
// Sessions are short-lived, cheap to create and NOT thread safe. Typically create one or more sessions
// per request in your web application. Make sure to call Close on the session when done.
// For multi-database support, set sessionConfig.DatabaseName to requested database
// Session config will default to write mode, if only reads are to be used configure session for
// read mode.
session := driver.NewSession(neo4j.SessionConfig{})
```

So having a global `driver` instance is not an issue, but you should not be using a global `session` instance since it is not thread safe.

Comment: That's the doubt that I had while reading this readme. `Won't that mean that every time a repo function is called, a new session will be created?`. Isn't that less performant

Comment: Yes, it is less performant, however, not as bad as you might think, just the allocation of a struct: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-go-driver/blob/ba2e4ccabf7102e6886b2f75cac2f2cade983b4b/neo4j/session.go#L149. The actual connection is pooled and thus reused between sessions. So it is unlikely that session creation will be your bottleneck

Comment: That makes sensse. Although, the code that I wrote seems to be working when i remove the `defer session.Close()`. But what you explained seems like a safe bet. Thanks!

Comment: You code will work, but it is not thread safe, so you will get race conditions or strange bugs when you use `session` across multiple goroutines, which tends to happen, so it is not best practice, unless you know exactly what you are doing.